# Re-defining a dict key value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

This code doesn't work - is there another way I can add a key-value pair with a variable as the value?

```
BTC_ = {"Name": "BTC", "liq": 57000}
ETH_ = {"Name": "ETH", "liq": 50000}

BTC = BTC_['liq']
ETH = ETH_['liq']

ETHp = ETH / 50000
BTCp = BTC / 50000

BTC_.update['price': BTCp ]
ETH_.update['price': ETHp ]
```

This code currently gives the error:

```
Output: builtin_function_or_method object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please excuse my poor use of " and ' I've re written the code to condense the problem for ease but forgot to eye over this

Comment: `BTC_['price'] = BTCp`

Comment: You call functions with `()`, not `[]`

Comment: `BTC_.update(price=BTCp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `[]` to `()` and enclose the argument in `{}` (thus turning it into a dictionary):

```
BTC_ = {"Name": "BTC", "liq": 57000}
ETH_ = {"Name": "ETH", "liq": 50000}

BTC = BTC_['liq']
ETH = ETH_['liq']

ETHp = ETH / 50000
BTCp = BTC / 50000

BTC_.update({'price': BTCp})
ETH_.update({'price': ETHp})

print(BTC_)
print(ETH_)
```

Answer (score 3):

You call functions with `(arguments)` after the function name, not `[arguments]`. And the argument to `dict.update()` must be a dictionary or `key=value` named arguments. So the correct syntax would be:

```
BTC_.update({'price': BTCp})
# or
BTC_.update(price=BTCp)
```

But if you're just setting one element, this is normally done using assignment:

```
BTC_['price'] = BTCp
```

`.update()` is normally only used when you want to set multiple elements, often by merging with another dictionary.

Comment: What about `BTC_.update(price=BTCp)`?

Comment: Forgot about that, I updated.